# Simultaneous transmission of a D2D user

Tags: software-defined-radio

Can a D2D user (a device) transmit simultaneous different signals to a cellular user and a D2D receiver. If we suppose that the D2D device is equipped with SDR technology and can change their frequency channel while transmitting to a cellular user. Moreover will the time slots and power factors with which it is transmitting will be different in this case.

Comment: The biggest challenge might be obtaining a license to transmit in the cellular bands.

Comment: but if it is allowed to can it ?